# how to get other attributes corresponding an attribute

Tags: sql

I've got a table with ID information. Now I need to replace them with other attributes(such as name, grade) corresponding to each ID.

This is what I have:

```
1782    1709    1689
1911    1247    1468
```

This is what I expect:

```
Andrew  10  Cassandra 9   Gabriel  9
Gabriel 11  Alexis    11  Kris     10
```

Comment: If they're in the same table, just change the columns you're pulling. If not, you'll need a `JOIN`.

Comment: I tried to use join, but then I got error message: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression.

Comment: How do you know which values correspond to which other values?

Comment: There's a relation with two attributes: ID1,ID2, describing ID1 likes ID2. Also there's another relation with three attributes: ID, name and grade.   I was asked to find out all situations where A likes B, B likes a different people C. Then return the name and grade of A B and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two tables, one is Likes, with two attrbutes: ID1,ID2, describing ID1 likes ID2; one is Highschooler, with three attributes: ID, name, grade. The question asks to find out each situation where A likes B, but B likes a different person C, and then return the names and grades of A, B, and C.

I found out a solution:

select H1.name,H1.grade,H2.name,H2.grade,H3.name,H3.grade from

(select Like1.ID1 New1, Like1.ID2 New2, Like2.ID2 New3

from Likes Like1, likes Like2

where Like1.ID2=Like2.ID1 and Like1.ID1<>Like2.ID2) New, Highschooler H1, Highschooler H2, Highschooler H3

where New1=H1.ID and New2=H2.ID and New3=H3.ID;

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   case id
     when 1782 then 'Andrew 10'
     when 1911 then 'Gabriel 11'
     ...
   end as "name&grade"
from your_table;
```

If you need more complex solution, please attach more details about your schema.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't describe my question clearly, the question is like this: There's a relation with two attributes: ID1,ID2, describing ID1 likes ID2. Also there's another relation with three attributes: ID, name and grade. I was asked to find out all situations where A likes B, B likes a different people C. Then return the name and grade of A B and C.